# ios Finch library errors

Tags: finch

I'm planning on using Finch in my iOS project to play audio sound effects without delay.

I created a workspace with my project and Finch in. I've created the "Support" folder and linked User Header Search Paths there. Also I linked the libFinch.a to my project.

Following the demo code: I do

```
soundFactory = [[FIFactory alloc] init];
[soundFactory setLogger:FILoggerNSLog];

[self setSoundEngine:[soundFactory buildSoundEngine]];
[soundEngine activateAudioSessionWithCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback];
[soundEngine openAudioDevice];
```

When running on a iOS 4.3 device, Xcode gives me this error, and points me to FIFactory.m init method:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_storeStrong
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/20924112-6536-4200-84E2-E426CD8FC6F5/
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_storeStrong
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/20924112-6536-4200-84E2-E426CD8FC6F5/
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it’s an issue of linking a non-ARC project with an ARC-enabled static library, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756418).