# XMPP not working on iOS 4.3 project

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3, ios4, xmppframework

In My Xcode project I had integrated XMPP framework. It works fine on the iOS 5.1 simulator. When I tried to run the project on the iOS 4.3 simulator I am getting the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_storeStrong
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/67451DE6-EFC1-4313-9A29-C2C641F727C6/AppName.app/AppName
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_storeStrong
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/67451DE6-EFC1-4313-9A29-C2C641F727C6/AppName.app/AppName
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

The error occurred on the following line of code : `xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];`

After Further debugging I found that the error occurs here :

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) //**CRASH WHEN EXECUTING THIS STATEMENT
    {
        // Common initialization
        [self commonInit];

        // Initialize socket
        asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:xmppQueue];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The project I integrated XMPP is not an ARC. So I added **-fobjc-arc** against all XMPP files. The sample project given by XMPP library is working fine on the iOS 4.3 simulator. Can anyone help me in resolving this error?
**Xcode Version : 4.3.3

iOS : iOS 4.3 Simulator**

Answer (score 0):

If XMPP requires ARC and you are turning it explicitly off this kind of linker errors happen. 
Try removing `-fno-objc-arc` from XMPP files and adding `-fobjc-arc` in your Other Linker Flags of your project. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756418/static-library-with-arc-support-linked-to-non-arc-project-causing-linker-errors)

Comment: Sorry, I had already added -fobjc-arc against all XMPP files. But the issue persists

Comment: But that's a compile time step, not link time, right?. If I understand correctly, your project is non-ARC so ARC libs are not linked with by default. If some of your classes do require ARC, you need to explicitly link against them.